# Where can I find good practice questions for proofs by reduction?

Tags: provable-security, key-exchange, mac, reference-request, pseudo-random-function

I already have the Katz-Lindell textbook, but I also want some additional practice problems for security reductions for stuff like PRFs, MACs, digital signatures, private and public key schemes, and key exchange schemes. Where could I find more problems for practice?

Thank you!

Comment: Lecture Notes on Cryptography by Shafi Goldwasser and Mihir Bellare, and A Graduate Course in Applied Cryptography Dan Boneh and Victor Shoup. All free books.

Comment: Ah, thanks, these look like just what I need!

Answer (score 1):

A book Introduction to Security Reduction by Fuchun Guo;Willy Susilo;Yi Mu

Comment: Thanks for this, this looks good too!